# PHP: PCRE: preg_match_all won't match escaped dollar sign ($) within pattern

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I am trying to match all instances of the substring '${foo}' inside $content. I can match '{foo}' but not '${foo}' for some reason. Anyone know why?

```
$content="aaaa\${foo}bbbb\n";
echo $content; // aaaa${foo}bbbb

// THIS WORKS AS EXPECTED: matches all instances of substring '{foo}'
$result = preg_match_all("/(\{\w+\})/", $content, $matches);
if ($result === false) { die("NOT OK!"); }
echo "NUMBER OF MATCHES: ", $result, "\n";
var_dump($matches);

// THIS DOESN'T WORK AS EXPECTED: doesn't match instances of substring '${foo}'
$result = preg_match_all("/(\$\{\w+\})/", $content, $matches);
if ($result === false) { die("NOT OK!"); }
echo "NUMBER OF MATCHES: ", $result, "\n";
var_dump($matches);
```

Here is the output of this code. The first part outputs 1 matches, as expected, whereas the second part outputs 0 matches, but I was expecting 1 match:

```
aaaa${foo}bbbb
NUMBER OF MATCHES: 1
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "{foo}"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "{foo}"
  }
}
NUMBER OF MATCHES: 0
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  [1]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: When you use a double quotes to enclose a pattern string, you must escape the `$` sign twice. One time to prevent the php parser to see the `$` as the start of a variable, one time to escape the special regex character `$`. If you want to escape it only one time, use single quotes.

Comment: simply put, use single quotes for regular expressions. It will save you a headache.

Answer (score 2):

You need to double-escape the backslash (and you should double-escape the braces as well).

```
"/(\\$\\{\w+\\})/"
```

This is because you need to escape the backslash for the string parser, since `\\` will become `\` before PCRE even gets to see the string. Without the double-escape, PCRE will just get `$`, which obviously will try to match the end of the string.

Comment: You don't need to double escape the curly brackets most of the time. Only when it is ambiguous like `{1,2}` or `{1}` (and the opening bracket should suffices). However it isn't an error.

Answer (score 2):

Use single quotes so as to not have to double escape the $ sign. Only regular expression special characters need to be escaped when used in a regular expression in single quotes, apart from backslashes and single quotes which need to be escaped in any PHP string enclosed in single quotes. When using regular expressions only use double quotes when you need to embed a variable inside your regular expression (in which case other characters may need to be escaped as well as the other answers demonstrate).

Hence the following works:

```
$content="aaaa\${foo}bbbb\n";
echo $content; // aaaa${foo}bbbb

// THIS WORKS AS EXPECTED: matches all instances of substring '{foo}'
$result = preg_match_all('/(\{\w+\})/', $content, $matches);
if ($result === false) { die("NOT OK!"); }
echo "NUMBER OF MATCHES: ", $result, "\n";
var_dump($matches);

// THIS ALSO WORKS AS EXPECTED: matches all instances of substring '${foo}'
$result = preg_match_all('/(\$\{\w+\})/', $content, $matches);
if ($result === false) { die("NOT OK!"); }
echo "NUMBER OF MATCHES: ", $result, "\n";
var_dump($matches);
```

Comment: You'd still need to double-escape the `$`.

Comment: Only regular expression special characters need to be escaped in single quotes. Use double quotes in a regular expression only when you need to insert a variable value into the regular expression (in which case extra escapes may be required as this case points out).

Comment: Or backslashes or single quotes.

Comment: Yes, exactly, only those characters.

Answer (score 0):

Use single quotes on your pattern.

Example:

```
$pattern = '/(AUTH|PENALTY|(?:\$LINE))/i';
$DETTYPE_VALUE = array_filter($data, function($a) use($pattern)  {
    return preg_match_all($pattern, $a['fine']);
});
```